# Was my answer deleted?

Tags: support

How can I tell if my answer was deleted?
There's no evidence of the answer on my profile page, except for the fact that I have the `Teacher` badge.
I haven't recieved any notifications about this.
I can't find the question anymore (which was asked in the last 24 hours), but it was posted under the [php tag](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/php)
[My profile](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/19197/nick-odell)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It *was*, but not because of any specific issues with your answer. The *question* was deleted, and all answers with it.

Apparently, the person who asked the question had posted some code he really shouldn't have. He requested that it be removed, and a moderator complied.