# Should reputation be required to delete answered questions?

Tags: discussion

Should there be some reputation limit, below which an OP cannot delete an answered, up-voted question?

---

A "New contributor" asked a [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/281074/create-list-of-obstacle-locations-from-a-map/281087).  9 hours later, I first saw the question.  It wasn't a great question, but was on topic and wasn't terrible.  It had received 1 up vote, 1 down vote.  I cleaned it up a bit, gave it an up vote, and spent the better part of the next hour crafting a useful answer.

42 minutes later, the OP accepted my answer, ... and 61 seconds after that, deleted their question!

I agree an OP should have the right to delete a bad question.  This question had an net +1 vote, and was generating a net +18 rep for the OP, so I don't think it really qualifies as a bad question.

So what is happening here? The OP is ...?

1. trying to pass off improved code from answer on Code Review as their own work for a school project, and by deleting the question, it makes it difficult to impossible for the grader/colleague to find evidence of this?
2. just embarrassed by the quality of their original code?
3. helping Tim find his lost keys?

I realize we will probably never know.

I don't actually care about any real/potential loss in reputation due to the deleted answer on the deleted question.  I'm more annoyed by the loss in time.  But consider: I've got enough reputation to see the post's timeline, and can see there was one down-vote on the question, but no comments left on the question hinting at why, and the question was deleted by the OP.  Imagine I was a newer user, with only a few hundred rep.  I invest a significant portion of time crafting an answer, posting it, and later go back to check on how it was received, only to find it is missing, with no clues left as to why?  I might feel I'm wasting my time contributing to the site.  More negative experiences would compound this, and I might leave.  The community loses.

Excerpt from comment by Mast:

> The feature you ask for already exists, it simply didn't apply yet. An answer without any upvotes isn't considered properly answered yet by the system.

From [Why and how are some questions deleted](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions), we see the rules of said feature:

> You can't delete your own question if one or more of the following is true:
>
> - It has an answer with one or more upvotes (regardless of the answer's net score)
> - It has multiple answers (even if they have no upvotes)
> - It has an accepted answer
> - It has an answer (that isn't deleted) with an awarded bounty
> - Another question has been closed as a duplicate of it

From [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

> You might have had second thoughts about something you've posted. Maybe you don't want your coworkers to see that very specific question about job-hunting, or you realize you shouldn't have posted that proprietary code, or you don't want your friends to see that stupid mistake in your question. **If nobody has answered yet, go ahead and delete it — nobody minds.**
>
> If your question has good answers, though, it's not fair to have those answers removed along with your question: other users put effort into helping you and even if you no longer want the answers, somebody else might. This is why the system prevents you from deleting answered questions most of the time.

It looks like we might be in the middle here.  Someone posts an answer to question, but not enough time has passed for the community to vote on whether said answer is good or not.

At the top, I suggested a reputation limit, below which an OP cannot delete an answered, up-voted question?  I see the existing set of rules are well thought out and make sense.  Perhaps we just need a time-limit added to allow the community a chance to vote on and/or add additional answers.  Something like:

> You can't delete your own question if one or more of the following is true:
>
> - [... existing rules omitted for brevity ...]
> - 12 hours hasn't elapsed from the first undeleted answer

Thoughts?

Comment: Your question seems to ask some quite speculative questions (why did the OP do x?). However some parts of the core of your question are already answered in the question [Asker deletes question after posting an answer](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9165).

Comment: @Peilonrayz Yes, I asked some speculative questions.  I also tagged the question "discussion", 'cause I'd have liked to hear speculative answers.  Depending on the answers, I may have escalated it to a "feature-request" for a minimum reputation on self-deleting answered questions.  However, your linked question does spell out that "_a user is able to delete their posts as long as there are no upvoted answers on their posts_", so the protection I was looking for is already in place -- I was just unlucky in that no-one upvoted my answer in the intervening 42 minutes.

Comment: The answer to your speculative questions are; [Tim Post has lost his keys again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397).

Comment: I understand your concern, but we can not answer the 'why'. If the community thinks such posts should be undeleted, we can talk about undeletion votes. But this doesn't appear to be the focus of your question. The feature you ask for already exists, it simply didn't apply yet. An answer without any upvotes isn't considered properly answered yet by the system. Would you propose to remove this limitation?

Comment: @Mast No, I think that is a good limitation, but perhaps we need to allow time for an upvote to actually occur.

Comment: Related: [Question removed by OP after I answered it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257337/269301)

Comment: The question has been undeleted. Considering 2 of the moderators agreed we'd have voted to undelete it if we hadn't been moderators and you bringing it up, there were 3 'votes' against removing the question. I'm currently writing an additional answer to the [closely related meta question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9165/52915) already brought up by Peilonrayz so regardless of potential new features we'll have a route to deal with this.

Comment: If the answer there does suffice, it may be best to close this question as a duplicate of that one to keep the discussion centralized. If you want the feature preventing questions from being removed to be extended to, say, questions with answers less than 15 minutes old, you'd have to make a feature-request on [MSE](//meta.stackexchange.com). Feel free to link back to any CR meta questions there. You'd have my support, but network-wide feature requests require more than that to be implemented.

Comment: @Mast Agreed.  Voting to close your own question as a duplicate?  There aught to be a badge for that!